# how to confimr encrypted data in fiddler?

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, fiddler

I am testing https data encryption on local host. For this I have registered a certificate in IIS and attach to my aspx web site. When preview my site in IIS in browser it appears with https.

In form tag I have added another page as action and method is post.

After putting text in textbox and pressing button when I see in fiddler it shows plain data. I am expecting encrypted data there. Is there anything I am missing ? Or doing worng ?

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: have you enabled `Decrypt HTTPS Traffic` in fiddler options?

Comment: ajay_whis, Yes it is enabled. What changes I should do to see data in encrypted form.

Please also guide in which tabe under what area/ fields I can see encrypted data ?

Comment: That is why fiddler is able to show you the actual data, if you disable that option, you should only see the `connect:445` request in the fiddler

Comment: also look at the certificate from your browser, it should be fiddler generated one and not that you have applied